# Calculate FLOPS (Floating Point Operations per Second) of TensorFlow lite model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there any way to measure directly the FLOPS of a .tflite model? I've found some topics about this, but just to the unconverted model.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that measures the TFLite model performance. Please take a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement.

The benchmark tool can measure useful metrics including initialization time, Inference time, memory footprint and so on.